# Angular Form Validators incorrect email validation

Tags: angular, forms, validation, email

When using Angular Form Validators ( import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; ) from the official Validators with the following command:

```
Validators.email
```

The email validation is only very rudimentary and therefore wrong.
For Angular Validators this: "email@t" is a correct email adress, what is wrong of course.

Comment: Whatever js solution you end up with, make sure to validate it on api/server side too, and if your need is such - send validation email to inserted address for double security/certainty.

Comment: Yes, Angular just controls the Frontend of course.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is using "Validators.pattern" instead of "Validators.email".

```
Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')
```

This code will test the input of an correct email syntax.

Comment: TLDs can be longer than 4 characters.

Answer (score -1):

i used this and its working fine.

Validators.pattern("^([a-zA-Z0-9-._]+)@([A-Za-z-]+)\.([a-z]{2,3}(.[a-z]{2,3})?)$")

Comment: The allows even less valid emails than the existing answer.